# Treatment of a scanned logo with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, scanner

I have an image produced by a scan of a logo, that is supposed to have only one tonality. The pixels close to the edge of the logo have various levels of density.

The use will require it to go over other background colors and to have its own (different) color, that is:

- it needs a transparent background
- to be re-coloured in several tonalities

The starting image outputed by the scanner has a background that is white-29%-transparent. I would like to change it to into a fully transparent PNG and then also be able to use ImageMagic to change the tones.

[image]

The only way I could get close is to:

```
convert by level colors first
then change into a JPEG with white background
then changing it back to full-transparent
```

with commands:

```
convert image.png +level-colors red, red-image.png
convert red-image.png red-image.jpg
convert red-image.jpg -transparent "#ffffff" full-trans.png
```

which creates several artifacts, probably most from the JPEG stage.

It is possible to change the background of the PNG in one step without having to do all these conversions? Without passing by a JPEG?

Are there more standard procedures on how to treat a scanned image in this form?

Comment: To get rid of your 29% transparent white background in one step, try `convert -transparent white -fuzz 29%`.

Comment: I ran the commands on the image you provided and now see what you mean by artifacts. Maybe the advanced [background removal](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#bg_remove) techniques using masks can help you. I still don’t know why you convert to JPEG because red-image.png already has a white background for me.

Comment: @Devon, I tried your first recipe `convert image.png -transparent white -fuzz 29% im-trans.png`but did not manage to get a fully transparent background. Opening it under Gimp, I still have the background in white-29%-transparency.

Comment: @Devon, as for your second comment, I went into a JPEG because there the background become fully white (#ffffff) and then I can easily make it transparent with my third command `convert red-image.jpg -transparent "#ffffff" full-trans.png`.